# C/C++ header, dll, and exports

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, header-files

I am trying to understand the relationship between headers and exports. Given a dll such as `dnsapi.dll`. It exports 254 symbols, mostly functions. You can check this for example using dependencywalker.

Then we have `windns.h`, containing around 50 functions, see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/).

Questions:

- Why doesn't the `windns.h` contain all 254 elements that are exported by the `dnsapi.dll`?
- If there is not a 1:1 mapping between .dll and .h files, how can I find all belonging .h files given a dll?
- Why is the `dnsapi.dll` exporting functions/symbols, that are not
  contained in the `windns.h`? Is it possible to use these exported functions without having the header?

Comment: Perhaps the developer exports functions that are not published. Perhaps these functions can be used privately by other code supplied by the developer. Perhaps there are ANSI and Unicode variants. Generally you don't approach a problem by looking at the exported functions and trying to call them at random. Generally you have a problem which you try to solve using the published documented interface. Do you have an actual problem to solve?

Comment: because some api (not only from *dnsapi.dll*) is undocumented, and not declared in header files from *sdk/wdk*  *is it possible to use these exported functions without having the header?* - of course - if you know function signature - you can declare it yourself. then need look - are function exist in *lib* file from *sdk/wdk* - if yes - can use it. if no - you need yourself build *lib* too or use `GetProcAddress`

Comment: What Microsoft supports and documents, and can never change again, is a subset of what an OS library must do.  You can call them "backdoors" if you like, matters to the OS implementation and likely to change but should never matter to a user program.  They are commonly hidden by exporting only by ordinal but not by name.  Most notably there is an entire layer that marries the winapi to the native OS, almost none of them documented.  So they can improve the OS without risking breaking any existing programs.  The most radical change was at Vista, which did break programs that broke the rulez.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the windns.h contain all 254 elements that are exported by
>   the dnsapi.dll?

Perhaps dnsapi.dll used other headers to be built. You can see inside it that it also has Socket related functions, for example. Or developers just didn't want to document all symbols, once you can't find it on documentation. It's also possible that some functions are for internal use only, maybe some signature definitions are made in source files, everything is possible...

> If there is not a 1:1 mapping between .dll and .h files, how can I
>   find all belonging .h files given a dll?

Well, I don't see other way unless getting these symbols names on dependency walker, for example, and search on msdn. All functions have a Requirements section that tells which header it uses. You can also search in files for the symbols in the SDK (Windows Kits etc) folders on your machine using notepad++, for example, using the *.h filter.

> Is it possible to use these exported
>   functions without having the header?

It's possible to use once you know what are the functions signatures. Then you can do the function pointer cast safely.